# Installing ipython with readline on the mac

Tags: python, macos, readline, ipython

I am using ipython on Mac OS 10.5 with python 2.5.1 (I would actually like to use ipython for 2.6.1, but it doesn't seem to be available?)

I installed ipython via easy_install. It works but is missing gnu readline (needed for nice searching of command line history with ctrl-R, etc.)

I found a [blog post](http://www.brianberliner.com/2008/04/18/ipython-on-mac-os-x-105-leopard/) and other sources saying this could be fixed by

`sudo easy_install -f http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ readline`

However, this leads to build errors in `readline.c` , particularly undeclared functions like `rl_compentry_func_t` and `rl_catch_signals`.

Has anyone seen these errors? Is there another way to get ipython installed with readline?

Comment: If you want to use vi keys in your ipython, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394302/how-do-i-use-vi-keys-in-ipython-under-nix/10394328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install everything you need with essentially one command using MacPorts. First download and install MacPorts from http://www.macports.org/.

Then just do the following in the terminal:
1) sudo port -v selfupdate
2) sudo port -v install py26-ipython

That will install python2.6, ipython for python 2.6 and readline for you. The command to start ipython will be located at /opt/local/bin/ipython2.6

Comment: Sadly, as macports has fallen out of favor, I don't think this is the ideal solution any longer.  Most folks seem to prefer homebrew these days.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. In my defense, there was no homebrew when I answered the question.

Comment: Agreed.  It was a great answer, I just thought I'd mention it for folks who stumble on this via google.

Answer (score 34):

To install ipython on Snow Leopard or Lion without using MacPorts, you can simply do:

```
sudo easy_install readline ipython
```

(Note that if you use the "pip" to install readline, then ipython won't see the readline library, not sure why).

*Edit:*

If you had ipython installed remove it with

```
sudo pip uninstall ipython
```

or

```
pip uninstall ipython #for virtualenvs
```

Then make sure you have installed readline first and reinstall iptyhon

```
pip install readline ipython
```

For some reasons, if readline wasn't present during the installation, it will install itself without support for readline or it use the default mac readline.

Comment: There's a discussion on the virtualenv group about the pip problem. (Summary: pip doesn't place its readline in front of the incompatible pre-installed version in sys.path)
http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/browse_thread/thread/044400bab87d119c/0bf2816070524268?show_docid=0bf2816070524268

Comment: It does work now, if ipython is already installed it won't work. You can add that you need to uninstall ipython. Ipython probably compile without readline or with the mac readline

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Please feel free to edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me (I'm using python 2.7, for other versions you'll need to edit):

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
sudo mv readline.so readline.so.bak
```

install readline however you want (pip, homebrew, macports, etc)

```
pip install -U readline
```

Success! and it works with virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper, and no need to modify ipython :)

Comment: Thanks! Based on this I was able to mend my self-installed but readline-broken Py 2.7 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Worked for me too, simplest way.

Comment: The sudo mv step is the only thing that fixed the problem for me on Mavericks. After that I did pip uninstall for both followed by 'pip install readline ipython' inside my virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

The only working way on MacOS Mavericks is to:

1. switch to your virtualenv `workon myproject_name`
2. delete readline and ipython (if you installed it before) `pip uninstall readline ipython`
3. install readline only via easy_install (pip - no work!) `easy_install readline`
4. finally install ipython with pip `pip install ipython`

It's work well on my MacOS and tested a long time.

Comment: This is the simplest solution I've found on Yosemite. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you don't want to use ports. **Caution: This is not upgrade safe.**

Install `ipython` and `readline` as normal:

```
sudo easy_install -f http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ readline ipython
```

Find the full path to your `readline` egg. For python 2.6 this will probably be:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/readline-2.5.1-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg
```

Edit `ipython` with your favourite text editor:

```
vim `which ipython`
```

Before the final line in the file `sys.exit`, insert:

```
sys.path.insert(0,'PATH_TO_READLINE_EGG')
```

Save and exit (`:wq`).

Check readline is working correct:

```
ipython
```

Comment: I don't use MacPorts (I prefer homebrew), and this was the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

"I would actually like to use ipython for 2.6.1"

It is available. I'm using it with 2.6.1 on os x. You just need to install the official python 2.6.1 distribution, then install ipython with easy_install.