# How Can I Use Turkish Alphabet In My Game For Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 2D Video Game as a school project which I am currently using Text Mesh Pro on. But there is an issue. Since my game is Turkish, I need to write on the Text Mesh Pro with special turkish letters such as Ç,Ş,İ etc. And to match with the pixel theme of my game, I tried converting a pixel font which includes Turkish letters in it but still it didn't work out. I used ASCII encoding to convert it into Text Mesh Pro, how can I solve this problem? Thanks already.

Comment: There is no "Turkish letters" in ASCII...

Comment: Is there a way that I can get turkish letters in my game? Other than ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

Unicode supports Turkish letters, and TextMeshPro supports Unicode. When creating your font asset, you have to include your characters in the asset. You can check the links below:

[Post explaining how to use Unicode for Turkish letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680059/how-to-define-declare-utf-8-code-points-for-turkish-special-chars-non-ascii-to)

[Unity Form Post Explaining how to Put Unicode Letters into your TextMeshPro Font Asset](https://forum.unity.com/threads/needs-unicode-support.483802/)